# Will there be any issues if I erase Windows and Install Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, installation, dynamic-disk

I have a laptop with Windows 10 on it. The hard drive of 1TB is dynamic. If I choose "Erase Windows and install Ubuntu" during Installation, will my disk being dynamic still cause any issues?

Answer (score 1):

Linux systems do **not** support dynamic disks. You will need to convert it to a basic disk.

If you want to keep all of your data on your disk (excluding windows), you will need to back up all your data somewhere else, then convert the drive to basic, then restore your data from the backup. See [This link](https://mypkb.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/how-to-non-destructively-convert-dynamic-disks-to-basic-disks/)and [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv).

If you don't care about losing any data, then follow the instructions above, minus the backing up.

Comment: I really do not have much data on my laptop.. and yes I have backed it up.

Comment: So by your answer can I conclude that Linux(Ubuntu) itself will fix the dynamic disk problem by erasing all the contents during installation? Note : I don't want dual boot, I want to completely erase windows and have Ubuntu instead on my laptop.

Comment: As long as you 100% erase your disk before proceeding, yes it should. I assume you're using a relatively new Ubuntu as well?

Comment: Yes I am Using 20.04 LTS

Comment: Ok then it should be fine